# How to find the index of the maximum over a subset of elements in julialang?

Tags: julia

I have an array `A=[3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10, 2, 3]` of length `length(A)=9` and a set `S` that contains a subset of the indices `1:9`, e.g., `S=Set([1, 3, 6, 8])`. I would like to find the maximum (the value and the index) of `A` over `S`. That is, the maximum is `9` and the index is `6`.

I tried to do it this way

```
A = [3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10, 2, 3];
S = Set([1, 3, 6, 8]);
B = [if i in S A[i] else 0 end for i in 1:length(A)];
findmax(B);
```

but I feel like there is a better and clever way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about?

```
julia> maximum((A[i],i) for i in S)
(9, 6)
```

This relies on the fact that tuples are sorted in lexicographical order. This only iterates over the subset, so it should be faster when `S` has significantly fewer elements than `A`.

`maximum` is a better choice than `findmax` here as Dan Getz pointed out.

Comment: If you wrap the expression with `first(...)` then the output is cleaner

Comment: or just use `maximum((A[i],i) for i in S)`

Comment: If I have multiple maximum and I would like to find them all, can we still use your approach? Like if `A` was equal to `A = [3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9, 10, 2, 9]` and `S=Set([1, 3, 6, 8])`. Your approach `maximum((A[i],i) for i in S)` gives `(9, 6)` instead of `(9, 3)` and `(9, 6)`.

Answer (score 5):

This is more verbose, but on my computer roughly 2.5x as fast as the generator solution (version 0.6):

```
function mymax(A, S)
    val, ind = typemin(eltype(A)), -1
    for i in S
        val_ = A[i]
        if val_ > val
            val, ind = val_, i
        end
    end
    return val, ind
end
```

Comment: I get the same result on my computer with the `S` and `A` given in the OP. If I instead make `A` 10^4 elements and `S` 10^3 elements, your code is 1.2X faster. (Also 0.6)

Comment: There is apparently some overhead to generators, they allocate memory, unlike the loop. I wonder if that is unavoidable. Generators are so cool, it would be great if they were also super fast.

Answer (score 3):

If `A` would contain no duplicates (or at least, the maximum were unique), I'd find the following more readable:

```
julia> i = findfirst(A, maximum(A[i] for i in S))
6
julia> A[i], i
(9, 6)
```

The `maximum` works on a generator, so there should be no memory overhead.  If `S` is small, the size of `A` dominates, and you have to traverse that anyway.

Comment: Pls check this one `A = [1, 1]; S=Set([2]);i = findfirst(A, maximum(A[i] for i in S));println("found $((A[i],i)) but is i in S? $(i in S)!")`  !

Comment: @Liso Thanks for pointing that out. I've added a precondition.

Answer (score 2):

In case there is more maximums you could do:

```
function maximums(A,S) 
    maxvalue = maximum(A[i] for i in S)
    (maxvalue, [i for i in S if A[i]==maxvalue])
end

A = [3,3,3]
S = Set([1,3])
maximums(A, S)  # (3, [3, 1])
```

If you like to preserve order and Set is not necessary type for S then you could use `unique` function:

```
S = unique([1,3])
maximums(A, S)  # (3, [1, 3])
```